# Regex for parsing parameters from url

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, parsing, url

I'm a total noob with regexes and although I was trying hard I cannot create proper regexes to perform the following operation :

1. take url and check if it has a '`?`' followed by number with varying amount of digits.
2. if the match is correct, get the number after the '`?`' sign
3. exchange this number with different one.

So let's say we have this url :

http://website.com/avatars/avatar.png?56

we take '`56`' and change it to '`57`'.

I have the following regex for searching, I'm not sure if it's proper :

```
\?[0-9]+
```

But I have no idea how to take `?` away. Should I just throw it away from the string and forget about using regex here ? Then the replace part is the only one left.

Comment: Is there a specific reason to use a regex? You could use the `location` object, respectively `location.search`.

Comment: Your regex is a-ok. You just need to add back in the `?` you take out. See my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex  will work just fine, just add back in the `?` you are taking out like so:

```js
var newnum = 57;
url = url.replace(/\?[0-9]+/, '?'+ newnum);
```

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

```
var url = "http://website.com/avatars/avatar.png?56"; 
var match = url.match(/\?(\d+)/); 
if(match != null) {
   url = url.replace(match[1], "new number");
}
```

Comment: Actually, no, `matches[1]` will be `"56"`, and the replace statement is effectively: `url = url.replace('56', "new number");` and the URL value ends up being: `website.com/pathnew number/avatar.png?56`.

Answer (score 0):

**VERY** dummied-down approach:

```
$('#parse').click(function(e){
    var fromUrl = $('#from-url').val();
    var newNum = parseInt($('#new-number').val(), 10);

    var urlRE = /(?!\?)(\d+)$/;
    if (urlRE.test(fromUrl)){
        $('#result').text(fromUrl.replace(urlRE, newNum));
    }else{
        $('#result').text('Invalid URL');
    }
});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/aHxKh/)**

There are not extravagant check-sums, error-checking, etc. Fromt here, use `window.location` or a string containing the URL if necessary.

---

Broken out in to a function ([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/aHxKh/1/)):

```
// Call this to replace the last digits with a new number within a url.
function replaceNumber(url, newNumber){
    // regex to find (and replace) the numbers at the end.
    var urlRE = /\?\d+$/;

    // make sure the url end in a question mark (?) and
    // any number of digits
    if (urlRE.test(url)){
        // replace the ?<number> with ?<newNumber>
        return url.replace(urlRE, '?'+newNumber);
    }

    // invalid URL (per regex) just return same result
    return url;
}

alert(replaceNumber('http://website.com/avatars/avatar.png?56', 57));
```

Comment: The expression `/(?!\?)(\d+)$/` is equivalent to `/(\d+)$/` (The negative lookahead assertion will _always_ be true at the position of a digit!)

Comment: @ridgerunner: They wanted to confirm that the link ended with a question mark **and** numbers. The negative look-ahead validates that. (Unless I'm misunderstanding what you're stating)

Comment: No, the negative lookahead does no such thing. It is a zero width assertion applied immediately preceding the first digit - it does not verify that the character before the first digit is a question mark. Remember that lookahead and lookbehind assertions are applied _between_ characters, In this case, between the question mark (if its actually there), and the first digit.

Answer (score 0):

I'm no regex expert but I think you can use a [lookaround](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) to ignore the '?'

```
(?<=?)([0-9]+)
```

which should give you your number in the first match

Comment: this is very simple,you can split the matched values using the () 
there an example in above my post...

Comment: Javascript does not have lookbehind.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without regex.

```
var newNum = "57";
var url = "http://website.com/avatars/avatar.png?56";
var sUrl = url.split('?');
var rUrl = sUrl[0] + "?" + newNum;
alert(rUrl);
```

1. Split the URL at the `?`
2. This returns an array.
3. Add the first item in the array and the `?` and the new number back together.

http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/7dMur/

Comment: What if there is more than one `?` character? (The `?` is valid in both `?query` and `#fragment`.) Also, what if there are more query parameters (or a `#fragment`) following the number?

Comment: Thx @ridgerunner.  I didn't consider any of those scenarios because the OP said `check if it has a ? followed by number with varying amount of digits` and his example was `http://website.com/avatars/avatar.png?56`  I figured it was pretty clear cut.  But agreed, a more complex URL would require something else.